# What is the good strategy when dealing with Proguard, MultiDex, Testing and Product Flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-productflavors, android-multidex

I have an app that reference ~ 100K methods, with min Sdk = 16

Here is 2 option for assembling:

- Proguard shrink this bunch of methods to only 44K methods
- Use Multi Dex

Now I have some common use cases:

1. Run and debug on emulator and devices

   - It requires to be as fast as possible
2. Do tests (Integration and UI)

   - It requires to run (I have some issue running Espresso with MultiDex)
3. Make the Prod APK

   - It requires to be reliable and shrinked as possible

**Do you have guys some recommandation about the assembling strategy ?**

**3/ Prod**

- Use Proguard to reduce APK size
- Use Proguard to obfuscate
- Do not use Multidex as most as possible (it may failed)

**2/ Test**

- Use minSdkVersion 21 (I read that starting by 21 enable pre-dexing, that saves time)
- ???

**1/ Debug**

- Use minSdkVersion 21 (I read that starting by 21 enable pre-dexing, that saves time)
- ???

Here is the Gradle file :

```
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
            multiDexEnabled ???
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
            multiDexEnabled false
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        targetSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode ANDROID_BUILD_VERSION_CODE
        versionName ANDROID_BUILD_APP_VERSION_NAME
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            //  shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "debug"
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the proposal of @Muzikant, that I mainly agree, I summarized my today vision

- Try not using `MultiDex` if you can.

  - It may happen to reach the 65K number with the overhead of method brings with test libraries (so use MutliDex)
  - It may happen that MultiDex is faster than Proguard process (to be checked), so it could be interesting for debugging
- Try to use an APK for testing that is the closest to the release APK

**My recommendations are:**

1. as there are 3 builds cases, just make 3 buildTypes :

   - release
   - debug
   - validation (test is a reserved word)
2. use 2 flavors:

   - one for release with the `minSdkVersion` of your app
   - and one for development that uses a more up-to-date `minSdkVersion` (faster building, more features for testing, easier to use espresso...)
3. do not obfuscate for debugging
4. for using Proguard during the test phase, a specific keyword of the Gradle DSL is necessary  `testProguardFile('proguard-rules-test.pro')`
5. point the build that will be used for debugging with  `testBuildType = "validation"`
6. do obfuscate for testing (at least for UI system and functional tests on your CI system)
7. use the optimisation Proguard rules only for release `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')`, for testing and debug just use `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')`

**The architecture of my Proguard files is the following:**

1. one main file for **release** `proguard-rules-release.pro` that include a set of dedicated Proguard files with `-include proguard-rules-fabric.pro`
2. one second file for **debug** `proguard-rules-debug.pro` that include `proguard-rules-release.pro`
3. one third file for **debug** `proguard-rules-dontobfuscate.pro`
   that disable obfuscation
4. one forth file for **testing** `proguard-rules-test.pro` that include `proguard-rules-debug.pro` and the rules necessary for testing

**Here is the Gradle file:**

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION
    buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
            multiDexEnabled false

        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
            multiDexEnabled false
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x.y.app.z"
        targetSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode ANDROID_BUILD_VERSION_CODE
        versionName ANDROID_BUILD_APP_VERSION_NAME
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    // point thge build for testing
    testBuildType = "validation"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "debug"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro', `proguard-rules-dontobfuscate.pro`
        }

        validation.initWith(debug)
        validation {
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
            versionNameSuffix "test"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
            testProguardFile('proguard-rules-test.pro')
        }
    }
...
}
```

I still have some open points to solve :

- How to use the automatic debug signing of Android Studio for the validation build ? (but I'm not sure about the impact)
- I still have to add `proguardFiles` attribute in the validation BuildType while I have the `testProguardFile('proguard-rules-test.pro')` that include the debug !

Comment: maybe adding  validation.initWith(buildTypes.debug) for the first open point (to be checked)

Comment: I see the point "use the optimisation Proguard rules only for release getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), for testing and debug just use getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')" is given. Why is that we do not run tests with Optimized code ? I have done tests on my code with obfuscation, but I am facing problems with optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

I use proguard on both debug and release versions in order to avoid multidex.

my `build.gradle` file looks like that:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard_debug.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    debuggable true
}
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard_release.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    debuggable false
}
```

in order to minimze differences between debug and release, and to allow proper debugging of the debug build, the `proguard_debug.pro` file contains the following proguard instructions:

```
-include proguard_release.pro

-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-keep class my.package.name.** {*; }
```

That way, I only maintain a single proguard configuration (in `proguard_release.pro`) and the debug version is built using the same configuration but without obfuscating the code.

That configuration solves all mentioned issues:

1. No multidex is required (so no dilemma whether to use it with API
   21+, and you can use Espresso)
2. Debug and release builds are the same, except that debug build does not obfuscate your code

Comment: OK, good. Just note it may also have issues caused by obfuscation ! However building the apk is really slow for debugging & testing. Do you accommodate yourself with this delay?

Comment: Considering the alternatives, this is the best solution for me. Obfuscation is not an issue since the debug proguard config has a -dontobfuscate flag

Comment: Yes, I just says that obfuscation may bring bugs into the app. This is also good to test with

Comment: Is it possible to run instrumentation test cases with object injection when the code is obfuscated and optimized?